# Unable to fetch data from PostgreSQL table connected using Python

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, jupyter-notebook, data-science

I can fetch the data using this command:

```
connection = psg.connect( database = "Test" , host="localhost", user="postgres", password="password")
data_1 = psql.read_sql('SELECT * FROM table_1 WHERE id IN (101 , 102)', connection)
```

But when I run the command below, it gives me an error. A user will put the dynamic ID values and it'll show the data corresponding to the respected IDs. That's why a variable is created which will be on user interface.

```
connection = psg.connect( database = "Test" , host="localhost", user="postgres", password="password")
variable_p = (108 ) # 108 is the id column value.
data_1 = psql.read_sql('SELECT * FROM table_1 WHERE id IN (variable_p[0])', connection)

Error - Column variable_p does not exist.
```

Answer (score 0):

you are not using your variable `variable_p` in your read sql string. You can use f-strings here:

```py
connection = psg.connect( database = "Test" , host="localhost", user="postgres", password="password")
variable_p = 108  # don't need parentheses for single value
data_1 = psql.read_sql(f'SELECT * FROM table_1 WHERE id = {variable_p}', connection)
```

But here you are vulnerable to SQL injection. So try parametrising your query to make it safe.

Parametrising and using `WHERE IN` this might be something like (untested):

```py
variable_p = (1, 2, 3)
data_1 = psql.read_sql('SELECT * FROM table_1 WHERE id IN %s', connection, params=variable_p)
```

Comment: This works well when variable_p = 108 but when variable_p can take 2 to 3 integer values like variable_p = 101 , 102 , 108 then it does not work , Error - operator does not exist: integer record.

Comment: Yes, building a dynamic and safe `WHERE IN` string can be a bit fiddly due to the risk of SQL injection.

Comment: @Andrew I've updated the answer with a suggestion.

Comment: again i have got the error by using your updated code .Error : Execution failed on sql : not all arguments converted during string formatting.

Comment: Perhaps params is expecting a list, try `params=[variable_p]`.